# Were the queens present in camps during Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, draupadi, subhadra

Were there any queens like Draupadi, Subhadra or any wife of Kauravs or other important warriors, present in their respective camps during the war of Mahabharata. (I mean only in the camps, not in the battlefield).

Or were they all left at homes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the part where it is described that after the destruction of Duryodhan's army, the ladies of the royal household went to the city of Hastinapur, It clearly suggests that at least Kaurav's side ladies were present in the camps.

From English translation of K M Ganguli of [Shalya Parva Chapter 29](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m09/m09029.htm):

> O monarch, the old men that had been appointed to look after the ladies of the royal household proceeded towards the city, taking the princesses after them.
>
> Then the friends of Duryodhana, deeply afflicted and made voiceless by their tears, set out for the city, taking the ladies of the royal household with them. The camp-guards quickly fled towards the city, taking with them many white beds overlaid with costly coverlets. Others, placing their wives on cars drawn by mules, proceeded towards the city. Those ladies, O monarch, who, while in their houses could not be seen by the very sun, were now, as they proceeded towards the city, exposed to the gaze of the common people.